# yammer embed comment not displaying reply option on mobile

Tags: javascript, yammer

The yammer embed script to show the open graph comments about the page is not showing the reply to comment option in small screens. In desktop and tablets it shows. But in mobile it is not showing the 'write reply' text box. The embed script is as as below.

```js
yam.connect.embedFeed({
 feedType: "open-graph",
 feedId: parseInt(appConfig.YammerFeedId, 10),
 network: appConfig.YammerNetwork,
 config: {
  use_sso: true,
  header: false,
  footer: false,
  showOpenGraphPreview: false,
  defaultToCanonical: false,
  promptText: appConfig.YammerCommentPromptText,
  defaultGroupId: parseInt(appConfig.YammerDefaultGroup, 10),
  hideNetworkName: false
 },
 objectProperties: {
  url: location.href,
  type: "page",
  fetch: false,
  "private": false,
  ignore_canonical_url: true
 },
 container: "#yammer_comment"
});
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/requirements) "only desktop browsers are supported with Yammer Embed at this time."